# Datetime UTC format. Not recognized by POST request? [OANDA]

Tags: java, php, datetime, curl

I'm trying to create an order using the OANDA REST api endpoints.

http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/orders/#createNewOrder

I'm having trouble with setting the expiry variable during the request, as I am trying to create a limit order, so I have to set it.

The code I use to generate the format for the UTC datetime generates a date of this

```
2016-04-23T15:57:05.000Z
```

However I get this message

```
POST https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/accounts/<accNumber>/orders&instrument=EUR_USD&units=1&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-04-23T15:57:05.000Z&price=1.0 HTTP/1.1
{"code":38,"message":"No matching handler for request with uri \/v1\/accounts\/309077\/orders&instrument=EUR_USD&units=1&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-04-23T15:57:05.000Z&price=1.0","moreInfo":"http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/troubleshooting\/#errors"}
```

Perhaps its something about the UTC DateTime needing to be encoded? I made a curl request with a URI encoded date time but got this message still.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX-YYY" --data "instrument=EUR_USD&units=1&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&price=1.0" https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/accounts/<Acc Number>/orders

{
    "code" : 41,
    "message" : "Received request with malformed body: 'instrument=EUR_USD&units=1&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&price=1.0'",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/troubleshooting\/#errors"
}
```

The only message I can get differently than a malformed body is when I send a curl request with an expiry like this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX-YYYYY" --data "instrument=EUR_USD&units=1&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-04-01&price=1.0" https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/accounts/<Acc Number>/orders
{
    "code" : 1,
    "message" : "Invalid or malformed argument: expiry",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/troubleshooting\/#errors"
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've successfully created limit orders with the body: `instrument=EUR_USD&units=1000&side=buy&type=limit&expiry=2016-02-10T07%3a06%3a50Z&price=1`. Hopefully you've figured out the issue but from what I see there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Upon further inspection, your first call is wrong, which you may have realized in subsequent attempts. You use & to begin your query string, which should be ?. Even so, that's not proper syntax for POSTing, as OANDA expects your parameters to be sent in the body of the request. Expecting a query sting in the body is a bit odd to me, but that's their design. Still not sure why you second attempt didn't work. I take it the proper bearer token was passed, and the proper account id.

Comment: Second attempt fails on the dateFormat. It's only the date, with no time specified: `&expiry=2016-04-01&price=1.0"`